# Is Deleting Event log that danger?

Tags: windows, event-log

I have an application, which keeps track of some logs since its installation time.

Since the system log may be huge, my application's performance is too bad if the log is too large, but if we cleared the log just before installation, it will be much much better.

I know it is not my right to do so, but for now I am searching for its security issues.

So, will it considered - regardless the ethics - danger clearing the log named "system" only?

Comment: So the performance of querying the system event log is not acceptable?  What are you using the log for? Is it not only a problem when your application runs for the first time & has to "catchup"?

Comment: WMI query, I don't know if there is another faster way, although I were specified with my conditions in the select query,, may be I should use "select some columns where .. " instead of select * where .., Thanks for the inspiration :)

Comment: well, selecting specified fields hasn't helped :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you want. There is no danger in deleting any of the logs, as they are only there for your records to help you diagnose issues.

If you are confident that you or anyone else using the computer won't need the system logs then go ahead and delete them.

If I were installing it on my machine I wouldn't want it doing this without my explicit permission though, so maybe have a message to explain to the user that it might run slow if you choose not to delete them.